# Existence of some linear mappinng's problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Asume that $X$ is a linear finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $W$ is its subspace. 
Let $f$, $h$ be linear mappings from $X$ to $X$ such that $f(X)=W$ and $h(X) \subset W$.
Is there a linear mapping $g:X \rightarrow X$ such that

$$
h=f\circ g   
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Does there exist a linear $s \colon W \to X$ with $f\circ s = \operatorname{id}_W$? How would that $s$ help you answer the question?